# stacFastApi pgstac problem or condition in search

Tags: python, error-handling, request, response, geojson

When I try to do a search with query in search API it gives me error

stac-fastapi

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/search/
```

```
{
    "code": "RequestValidationError",
    "description": "2 validation errors for Request\nbody -> query -> or -> __key__\n  value is not a valid enumeration member; permitted: 'eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'lte', 'gt', 'gte' (type=type_error.enum; enum_values=[<Operator.eq: 'eq'>, <Operator.ne: 'ne'>, <Operator.lt: 'lt'>, <Operator.lte: 'lte'>, <Operator.gt: 'gt'>, <Operator.gte: 'gte'>])\nbody -> query -> or -> __key__\n  value is not a valid enumeration member; permitted: 'eq', 'ne', 'lt', 'lte', 'gt', 'gte' (type=type_error.enum; enum_values=[<Operator.eq: 'eq'>, <Operator.ne: 'ne'>, <Operator.lt: 'lt'>, <Operator.lte: 'lte'>, <Operator.gt: 'gt'>, <Operator.gte: 'gte'>])"
}
```

How do I create a query with the OR condition?

Comment: REQUEST
{
    "query": {
        "or": {
            "naip:year": {
                "eq": "2011"
            },
            "eo:cloud_cover": {
                "eq": 28
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: I change query with filter and used CQL2

{
    "filter": {
        "or": [
            {
                "=": [
                    {
                        "property": "eo:cloud_cover"
                    },
                    28
                ]
            },
            {
                "=": [
                    {
                        "property": "landsat:wrs_row"
                    },
                    28
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}